# Location attribute is not working for PageBlockButtons

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm trying to use command buttons using a dynamic component. I want to render these command buttons on the bottom of the page but I'm not able to do it. when I use `location=top`, it works. when I use `location=bottom`, I can't see the buttons at all. When I use `location=both`, I see them only at the top. I'm not using any facets. Please help me if someone knows!

I used them using apex code.

This is the VF page:

```
<apex:page title="Opportunity Display" controller="MyPageController1" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" readOnly="true" cache="false" >
    <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="SOQL Offset Example w/Dynamic Page Buttons" title="Opportunity Display Table" />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myCommandButtons}" />
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!refreshGrid}"  name="queryByPage" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" >
                <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedPage}" value="" />
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Display (Total List Size: {!total_size})" collapsible="false">
                <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
                    <apex:pageMessages id="theMessages" />
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunity}" var="n" align="center">
                        <apex:column><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!n.checked}"/></apex:column>
                        <apex:column value="{!n.cat.Id}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!n.cat.Name}" />
                        <apex:facet name="footer">Showing Page # {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post the Apex code you're using to define `myCommandButtons`?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you've included the code you're using on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15048891/361599